# Python validation issues

Tags: python

So I'm trying to validate something to complete my coursework but it has been giving me these errors:

R:197, 4: The if statement can be replaced with 'return bool(test)' (simplifiable-if-statement)

R:197, 4: Unnecessary "else" after "return" (no-else-return)

I'm generally new to coding so I'm not entirely sure on how to implement the return bool(test) into my code. Hoping you guys could help me? I've found out that python is really sensitive with indentation, which is why I'm kind of iffy about the second error. Here is the code:

```
def in_range(number):
    """
    True or false
    """
    if number > 50 and number < 100:
        return True

    else:
        return False

answer = in_range(90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten that to:

```
def in_range(number):
    """
    True or false
    """
    return 50 < number < 100

answer = in_range(90)
print(answer)
```

...or, if you are required to use `bool()` nonetheless, just wrap it:

```
return bool(50 < number < 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The phrase `number > 50 and number < 100` evaluates to a boolean. If you simplify that phrase it will be `True` or `False`, so it's redundant to effectively say `if True: return True`. You can simplify the if-statement as a result.

Answer (score 0):

They're not fatal error messages, and should be quite easily understandable. All the interpreter is saying is that the algorithm can be better written as

```
def in_range(number):
    return 50 < number < 100
```

Answer (score 0):

When python interprets `if number > 50 and number < 100:`, a result of expression `number > 50 and number < 100` converts to `bool` and then executes first or second block (return True or False in your case). So you can simplify the statement just returning `number > 50 and number < 100`.

```
def in_range(number):
    """
    True or false
    """
    return number > 50 and number < 100

answer = in_range(90)
```

But it seems that you don't need a function here:

```
answer = bool(100 > number > 50)
```